# How to add numbers to the end of existing lines in a file in Windows Command script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Trying to add numbers to the end of lines of a file that looks something like this:

```
Id
CN04FIL002,21,,,cn04fil002.mhf.mhc,1,backupexec,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:32,
CN04FIL002,365,,,cn04fil002.mhf.mhc,1,backupexec,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:35,
CN04FIL002,3285,,,cn04fil002.mhf.mhc,1,backupexec,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:44,
CN04FIL002,9318,,,cn04fil002.mhf.mhc,1,backupexec,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:59,
CN04FIL002,3,,,cn04fil002.mhf.mhc,1,backupexec,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 11:01,
CN04FIL002,2373,,,cn04fil002.mhf.mhc,1,backupexec,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 11:29,
CN04FIL002,2684,,,cn04fil002.mhf.mhc,1,backupexec,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 11:10,
CN04FIL002,26,,,cn04fil002.mhf.mhc,1,backupexec,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 10:30,03/30/2017 11:23,
```

And so on. What I would like to do is write a script that adds incrementing numbers after the final comma in each line and saves the current number so the numbers can continue to increment each time the script is run. How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you have to put the numbers next time starting from the ending line last time you run the script? Did myself clear?

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what you want.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%i in (count.txt) do (
    set "linesCount=%%i"
)

set "numLine=0"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (file.txt) do (
    set /a "numLine+=1"
    if "!linesCount!" equ "0" (
       echo(%%i!numLine!>>file.new.txt 
    ) else (
       set /a "linesCount-=1"
       echo(%%i>>file.new.txt
    )
)

move /Y file.new.txt file.txt >nul 2>&1
echo(!numLine!>count.txt
```

I save in a file named count.txt the amount of lines processed last time. If it doesn't exists, that is, the script have never been run create count.txt with a zero inside. Just rename file.txt to your filename.

Comment: What is `echo(` please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm used to use `echo(` to print exactly what I want, e.g., `echo(bla> file.txt` would write just `bla` to `file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably the fastest method:

```cmd
@echo off
set "_FILE=textfile.txt"

for /F %%C in ('^< "%_FILE%" find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
< "%_FILE%" (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%COUNT%) do (
        set /A "INDEX=%%I-1"
        set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
        if !INDEX! GTR 0 (
            echo(!LINE!!INDEX!
        ) else (
            echo(!LINE!
        )
    )
    endlocal
)
```

This skips the first line (`Id`) which is considered to be a header.
The first index number appended is `1`.